# PowerShell Script to save pending Windows Updates

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a function that gives me the Windows Updates pending, but I need to run remotely. The problem is that the CSV file didn't save the correct info.
Whats its wrong?

```
     function Get-WUInfo
 {
    $msUpdateSession = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session
    $updates = $msUpdateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher().Search("IsInstalled=0").Updates
    $pendingUpdates = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

    $updates | % {

    $title = $_.Title

    if ($_.Title.ToLower().Contains("silverlight")){
        if($silverLightInstalled){
            $pendingUpdates.Add($title)}
    }

    else{
            $pendingUpdates.Add($title)
        }
    }

    $updatesCount = $pendingUpdates.Count

    if($updatesCount -gt 0){
        Write-Host "***** $updatesCount updates pending for Iris Awesome COmputer*****" -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Yellow
        $pendingUpdates | % { Write-Host $_}
    }

    else{
        Write-Host "***** No pending updates for $env:COMPUTERNAME*****" -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Green
    }
}



Invoke-Command -ComputerName dc01 -ScriptBlock ${Function:Get-WUInfo}| Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation "C:\temp\prueba.csv"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itLIr.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this script:

function Get-WinUpdates {
Param ($ServerName=$null
)

```
        $ComputerObject = New-Object PSObject

        Write-Host "### $Servername ####" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        $nombrearchivo = "$Servername"+".csv"
        Write-Host $nombrearchivo


            [ScriptBlock] $script = {


            $update = new-object -com Microsoft.update.Session
            $searcher = $update.CreateUpdateSearcher()
            $pending = $searcher.Search("IsHidden=0 and IsInstalled=0")
            $pending.Updates | ForEach-Object {
                                                $_.BundledUpdates | ForEach-Object {
                                                                                    $title = $_.title
                                                                                    $description = $_.description
                                                                                    new-object PSObject -Property @{
                                                                                                                    "titulo" = $title;
                                                                                                                    "descripcion" = $description;
                                                                                                                    "status" = 'Pendiente';
                                                                                                                    }
                                                                                    }
        
                                              } 
        
        
        
        
        }
        
        
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Servername -ScriptBlock $script | Select-Object "PSComputerName","titulo","descripcion","status" | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation "c:\temp\$nombrearchivo.csv"
```

Comment: If you replace those nested `forEach-object` commands with `ForEach($item in $group)` syntax, you could make thi seasier to read (no more scrolling out to California to read the full thing!)